# Set daemon options of Docker daemon

Tags: docker

I've installed Docker v17.03.1 and according to the documentation I need to setup daemon options in the `daemon.json`. I need to apply this configuration

```
echo "DAEMON_MAXFILES=1048576" >> /etc/sysconfig/docker
echo "OPTIONS=\"--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --insecure-registry ${registry}\"" >> /etc/sysconfig/docker
echo "DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT=10" >> /etc/sysconfig/docker
```

Regarding the options the Docker config (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd) reports the options in a list but where should I set up `DAEMON_MAXFILES` and `DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT`?

Comment: What OS have you installed on?

Comment: @AndyShinn ubuntu 16.04